# Update React to use Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have updated both *react* and *react-dom* to version 16.8.6, but I still get this error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

which is shown for this line of code:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

The complete code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Clicked {count} times</button>;
};
```

How to make sure I have updated react and react-dom to the newest version? I removed the packages from package.json and used this command to install them again:

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

And then I saw the *react* and *react-dom* be added to the package.json with the newest versions.

If the react and react-dom are correctly updated, how do I make Hooks work?

A piece of my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "3.9.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
"babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
"immutable": "3.8.2",
"moment": "2.21.0",
"prop-types": "15.6.1",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-grid-layout": "0.16.2",
"react-helmet": "5.2.0",
"react-jss": "8.6.1",
"react-loadable": "5.4.0",
"react-modal": "3.3.2",
"react-number-format": "3.5.0",
"react-redux": "5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.9",
"recompose": "0.30.0",
"redux": "4.0.0",
"redux-immutable": "4.0.0",
"redux-saga": "1.0.2",
"reselect": "3.0.1",
"styled-components": "3.3.2",
...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this piece of code is throwing the error? It looks fine.

Comment: Looks fine to me too.

Comment: Try giving your component a name and exporting that.

Comment: can you show your package.json. Also you might need to update your other libraries too

Comment: Your code works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/y7vm9y7n2x

Comment: @Tholle Yes, I am sure this is the piece of cothe that throws the error.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have now added some of my package.json

Comment: You might have changed your `package.json` without installing the new dependencies. Try `npm ci`

Comment: @Tholl I do not have package-lock.json, so the command did not work. I have tried to use npm install after the packages have been added to the package.json file

Comment: @ReidunMarie Have you also deleted your node_modules folder?  Do that and rerun npm install.

Comment: @sanjsanj that may be something that could solve my probelem. Somehow I managed to install all packages again, and then the Hooks worked!

Comment: Yeah, a trick for future reference is to try `npm ci` when these things happen (it does the same thing that you did above).